# How to use R-Tree for plotting large number of map markers on google maps

Tags: python, google-maps, cluster-analysis, r-tree

After searching SO and multiple articles I haven't found a solution to my problem.

What I am trying to achieve is to load 20,000 markers on Google Maps.

[R-Tree](http://trac.gispython.org/lab/wiki/Rtree) seems like a good approach but it's only helpful when searching for points within the visible part of the map. When the map is zoomed out it will return all of the points and...crash the browser.

There is also the problem with dragging the map and at the end of dragging re-running the query.

I would like to know how I can use R-Tree and be able to achieve the all of the above.

Comment: I'm not clear on how R-trees help, as they are designed to spatially partition collections of rectangles. Also, what scheme won't return all markers when the map is zoomed out?

Comment: Clustering won't return all markers but I am not clear how to combine the two R-Tree + clustering. R-Tree will return a rectangle and all points within the bounds but then all of these points would have to be clustered and sent to the client - seems very inefficient to me...

Answer (score 2):

As noted, R-Tree won't help you when you're looking at a zoomed-out view.  This problem is often addressed by marker clustering, because showing 20,000 points in a browser window isn't that useful.

[Marker Manager](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays.html#Marker_Manager) is an open source javascript library which addresses this, but there are others.

With a very great number of markers, you may need to look at server-side clustering, (where R-Tree may come in handy!).  [Here](http://www.quanative.com/2010/01/01/server-side-marker-clustering-for-google-maps-with-python/) is one discussion of it, and [its google cache](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=12&ved=0CBYQFjABOAo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.quanative.com%2F2010%2F01%2F01%2Fserver-side-marker-clustering-for-google-maps-with-python%2F&ei=63oSTPsii4edB8ek-ZED&usg=AFQjCNGtLafYh9q3u0rmUJz7Et6l-MXajA&sig2=AQoI09bHTq8wAnmjjLm6Cg) because link is dead at time of writing.

Comment: I know Marker Manager - it's good for up to 2000 markers. Server-side clustering might be necessary but my question is how to combine both solutions to accomplish what I need. Re-running clustering on each drag of the map or zoom will be very slow.

Comment: +1 to the answer! Google states the following: *In practical consequences, [Marker Manager] allows 10,000 markers to be distributed over a large area, and as long as only 100-200 are visible in any given viewport the user will see good performance corresponding to the 100 visible markers.*

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to bother with clustering, then just terminate your marker list at a preset number, maybe a few hundred (which you can determine by usability testing), and display some indication that there are more available as you zoom in